# Unstage committed changes but keep new files in index

Tags: git, git-reset, git-add

I want to split the last commit in two, so I use `git reset HEAD~1`, but then it loses track of the new files that were added by the commit (which were not tracked before), and I have to carefully add them back one by one. I often have *other* untracked files lying around waiting to be committed later, so this is annoying.

What I would like is a way to `reset` but keep the files added by the commit as empty, as if they had been added with `git add --intent-to-add` (i.e. `git add -N`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading [the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) more attentively, I found the answer.

This does exactly what I want: `git reset --mixed -N HEAD~1`

Comment: --mixed is default action. So you can just specify `git reset -N HEAD~1`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I didn't understand very well, but isn't that a `git reset --soft`?

Comment: Not really, as I want to make several new commits out of these changes, so I still want to selectively add things instead of have everything already staged. Hope this makes sense, sorry if it was unclear!

Comment: So, just a `git reset HEAD` unstages the changed files and then you can add them as you commit them.

Comment: The whole point is that it loses track of new files (that were not tracked before the commit). I realize the term "added" is confusing in the context of git. I've made the question clearer.

Comment: This what I was looking for and it makes more sense from a Git perspective than `--mixed -N`